# building my own gnome3 distribution

Tags: linux, distribution, gnome

i am going to start building a personal linux Gnome3 based distribution

after lot of searching , i found some topics about fedora remixes but they
are not so much clear to me .

i've looked also on the official Gnome3 website but they don't offer any
tutorial on how to integrate Gnome3 on new distributions .

is there any good tutrials on how to make a Gnome3 based distribution ?

Comment: "they are not so much clear to me" How so?

Comment: they are talking about something without explanation for example they are talking about kickstart files but they never defined what are these files and how to deal with them

Comment: That's because there are other resources that explain what those are.

Comment: Why do you want to build your own distribution? Is there a special reason our is it 'just for interest' ?